# Getting width of dynamically generated HTML with JQuery

Tags: jquery

Using dynamically generated HTML, to format data from a transport feed, I am pushing elements to the front-end like so:

```
items.push("<div id='dock" + key +"' class='cycles pop-up'><ul><li><h3><span>" + road + "</span></h3></li><li><p>" + bikeTotal + "</p><p>Cycles available</p></li><li><p>" + spacesAvailable + "</p><p>Empty docking spaces</p></li></ul></div>");
```

Then when I try to to get the width of the `<h3>`, with JQuery, it returns null.

```
var availableWidth = $('.pop-up ul li h3').on('load', function(){
        console.log($(this).width());
    });
```

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong?

EDIT:

Code used to append to body:

```
$( "<div/>", {
    "class": "cycle-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
}).appendTo( "body" );
```

Comment: `h3` doesn't have a `load` event handler. Is that element even rendered on the page?

Comment: Did you insert it into the DOM? A string in an array doesn't really load anything.

Comment: I can see the element in the code inspector, if that is what you mean?

Comment: How is it appended to your page? The first line of code just shows you pushing it to an array.

Comment: I 'appendTo' the 'body.

Comment: Show the code appending the item to your document

Comment: Cool, edited the main post.

Comment: You can see a live example here:

Comment: http://tfl.applied-espi.com/cycles-popup/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `load` event for `<h3>`. Normally you should be able to get the width of the first in the collection by using

```
console.log($('.pop-up ul li h3').width());
```

However, the items are being appended when an AJAX call completes. Meaning they are non existent when you are attempting to log the width. If you place that line in your AJAX callback function, after they are appended, you'll get the result your looking for:

```
$.getJSON("cycles.php", function(data, index) {

    //the rest of your code

    $( "<div/>", {
        "class": "cycle-list",
        html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "body" );

    console.log($('.pop-up ul li h3').width());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {
  $('.pop-up ul li h3').each(function () { console.log($(this).width()); });
});
```

Assuming the following markup.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3></h3>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Still the same, returns 'null'.

Comment: Take a look at your DOM through the inspector. It should reflect the assumed markup. That could be your issue.

Comment: Yeah, you can see in the question that is the hierarchy of elements that are pushed. See here: http://tfl.applied-espi.com/cycles-popup/

Comment: Interesting. You might have have to try using `each()`. I'll update my post.

Comment: That doesn't even say null or undefined... So odd!